# Use openLDAP with meteor JS

Tags: meteor, ldap, meteor-blaze, meteor-accounts

I need to implement LDAP authentication for a Meteor App, and as we do not have LDAP server currently present.

Can I use OpenLDAP for implementation on my local machine.

I do not know a lot about LDAP authentication.. So I can appreciate any help I can get.. I am implementing this below mentioned piece of code which my friend has provided

```
        Template.ldapLogin.events({
        'submit #login-form': function (e) {
            e.preventDefault();
            var form = $(e.target);
            var username = form.find("#login-form-username").val();
            var password = form.find("#login-form-password").val();

            if (username === "admin") {
            Meteor.loginWithPassword(username, password, function (error) {
                if ( ! error && password === "admin") {
                // Set switch to trigger alert to change password
                Session.setPersistent("passChangePrompt", 1);
                }
            });
            } else {
            Meteor.loginWithLDAP(username, password,
                { dn: "uid=" + username + ",ou=<foo>,dc=<bar>,dc=<baz>,dc=<qux>" },
                function (error, success) {
                if (error) {
                    console.log(error.reason);
                } else {
                    FlowRouter.redirect('/');
                };
            });
            }
        }
        });
        Server:

        Meteor.startup( function() {
        LDAP_DEFAULTS.url = 'ldap://<ask your IT dude or gal>';
        LDAP_DEFAULTS.dn = 'ou=<foo>,dc=<bar>,dc=<baz>,dc=<qux>';
        LDAP_DEFAULTS.port = '';
        LDAP_DEFAULTS.searchResultsProfileMap = [
            {
            resultKey: 'cn',
            profileProperty: 'name'
            }
            ,{
            resultKey: 'mail',
            profileProperty: 'phoneNumber'
            }
        ]
        });
```

Thanks again

Answer (score 0):

Yes; you can install and run OpenLDAP on your local development machine. The default LDAP port is 389 which you have not defined. All depending on your OS, you might have open the port. The default TLS-enabled port is 689.

Before tackling the Meteor interface, validate your LDAP server configuration and LDAP authentication, called an LDAP BIND, by using and LDAP client to BIND, i.e., authenticate, to your LDAP server. Once you have validated the authentication, it's just SMOP Meteor.